# Speeding up function that uses which within a sapply call in R

Tags: r, sapply

I have two vector `e` and `g`. I want to know for each element in `e` the percentage of elements in `g` that are smaller. One way to implement this in R is:

```
set.seed(21)
e <- rnorm(1e4)
g <- rnorm(1e4)
mf <- function(p,v) {100*length(which(v<=p))/length(v)}
mf.out <- sapply(X=e, FUN=mf, v=g)
```

With large `e` or `g`, this takes a lot of time to run. How can I change or adapt this code to make this run faster?

Note: The `mf` function above is based on code from the `mess` function in the dismo package.

Comment: You could change mf to `mf <- function(p,v){100*mean(v<=p)}` but I'm not sure how much that will help.

Comment: Thanks Dason, but that seems to take more time

Comment: `vapply` instead of `sapply` will probably help.

Comment: @Paulo Does it really?  It takes less time on my system...

Comment: @Dason, no, it doesn't, you were right, your solution takes less time. I must have made a mistake when testing yesterday, sorry.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The reason this is so slow is because you're calling your function `length(e)` times.  It doesn't make a large difference for small vectors, but the overhead from R function calls really starts to add up with larger vectors.

Normally, you would need to move this to compiled code, but luckily you can use `findInterval`:

```
set.seed(21)
e <- rnorm(1e4)
g <- rnorm(1e4)
O <- findInterval(e,sort(g))/length(g)

# Now for some timings:
f <- function(p,v) mean(v<=p)
system.time(o <- sapply(e, f, g))
#   user  system elapsed 
#   0.95    0.03    0.98
system.time(O <- findInterval(e,sort(g))/length(g))
#   user  system elapsed 
#      0       0       0 
identical(o,O)  # may be FALSE
all.equal(o,O)  # should be TRUE

# How fast is this on large vectors?
set.seed(21)
e <- rnorm(1e7)
g <- rnorm(1e7)
system.time(O <- findInterval(e,sort(g))/length(g))
#   user  system elapsed 
#  22.08    0.08   22.31
```

Comment: Thanks @Joshua , great answer. The speed improvement is amazing. One small correction to get the same output as in the original function: findInterval(e,sort(g))/length(g)