# match() to list of vectors - of possibly different lengths

Tags: r, list, vector, match

The `match(x, y)` function is perfect to search the elements of the vector `x` within the elements of vector `y`. But what is an efficient and easy way to do the similar job when `y` is a list of vectors - of possibly different lengths?

I mean the result should be a vector of the same length as `x`, and the i-th element should be the first member of `y` that contains the i-th element of `x`, or `NA`.

Comment: Do you mean something like `lapply(y, match, table = x)`?

Comment: Perhaps the hesitation to upvote Josh's answer is due to confusion about your desired result. Do you want the index of `y` where each element in `x` is first found? Or do you want a list of length `y` with indices of each element that match the elements of `x`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To find the element of y in which each element of x (first) occurs, try this:

```
## First, a reproducible example
set.seed(44)
x <- letters[1:25]
y <- replicate(4, list(sample(letters, 8)))
y
# [[1]]
# [1] "t" "h" "m" "n" "a" "d" "i" "b"
# 
# [[2]]
# [1] "c" "l" "z" "a" "s" "d" "i" "u"
# 
# [[3]]
# [1] "b" "k" "e" "g" "o" "i" "h" "j"
# 
# [[4]]
# [1] "g" "i" "f" "r" "h" "w" "l" "o"

## Find the element of y first containing the letters a-j
breaks <- c(0, cumsum(sapply(y, length))) + 1 
findInterval(match(x, unlist(y)), breaks)
# [1]  1  1  2  1  3  4  3  1  1  3  3  2  1  1  3 NA NA  4  2  1  2 NA  4 NA NA
```

Comment: Extremely creative answer! Thanks

Comment: @AliSharifi -- Thanks. I kinda liked it myself!

Comment: Brilliant! A slight refactor of the breaks: `breaks <- cumsum(c(1, sapply(groups, length)))`

Comment: @nachocab -- Yes, that's better. Thanks for that, and for bringing me back here. `findInterval` can be a real gem of a function! ([See here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12982152/speeding-up-function-that-uses-which-within-a-sapply-call-in-r/12982624#12982624) for a cool example.)