# R: Compare vectors of differing lengths

Tags: r, vector, simulation

I'm actually having trouble phrasing my question, so if anyone has feedback on that, I'd love to hear it.

I'm working in R and have a vector and a data frame, of different lengths:

```
xp.data <- c(400,500,600,700)
XPTable <- data.frame("Level"=1:10,"XP"=c(10,50,100,200,400,600,700,800,900,1000))
```

What I'm hoping to obtain is a new vector:

```
> lv.data
[1] 5 5 6 7
```

The goal is to do so without using a loop, as the `xp.data` vector can be any length, and the `XPTable` data frame can also be of varying lengths.

If I was doing this without a vector for `xp.data`, I'd just use:

```
max(XPTable$Level[XPTable$XP < XP.data])
```

However, this only works if XP.data has a length of 1.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
    lv.data <- findInterval(xp.data, XPTable$XP)
    print(lv.data)
    # [1] 5 5 6 7
```

Comment: Borrowed the idea from: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24001788/how-to-find-in-which-quantile-bin-does-a-number-fall